# Как после выполнения теста selenium запустить скрипт на питоне?

Tags: python, selenium, тестирование

Есть тест на selenium, сгенерированный selenium ide. Он скачивает с сайта файл .xls, есть скрипт на питоне, который проверяет этот файл на корректность. Как после выполнения теста автоматически запускать этот скрипт?

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать запустить тест и скрипт одновременно. А в начале пайтон скрипта делать проверку открыт еще файл .xls или уже закрыт (загружен). Это можно делать функцией open(), если генерируется исключение IOError, тогда продолжаем переодически проверять, если файл открылся, то проверяем его на корректность.